# Multiple jquery datatables on same page causing width issue. (Datatables v10.13)

Tags: datatables, width

It causes width issue for both tables. Refer the code below,

```
<table id="tblMessages" class="table table-striped table-bordered full-width table-advance table-hover table-condensed fl" style="border-collapse:collapse !important;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:20%">From</th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:60%">Subject</th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:20%">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is second table,

```
<table id="tblToDos" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance full_width table-hover table-condensed fl" style="border-collapse:collapse !important">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:5%"></th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:20%">From</th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:30%">Patient</th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:35%">Subject</th>
                        <th style="cursor:pointer; width:10%">Reminder Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Note that I tried with giving width in "Columns" property of Datatables but no luck.

And if I removed second table init then it is working fine.

Comment: What is exactly the issue with width of the columns? Can you show a screenshot of the problem? Are these tables visible initially? There could be an issue with column widths if table is hidden initially (in a tab, accordion section)

Comment: Both tables are displayed but the column width has been set to auto width automatically.

Comment: Try disabling [`autoWidth`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) option and specify column widths during the initialization usint [`columns.width`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) option.

Comment: Already did that change but doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Though it is not a proper solution but we can solve this matter by redraw the grid using below code.

```
$('#tblMessages').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
```

Put this line after you are done with initialising second datatable.